# Design “Page Not Found” page for Mobile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web, 404-not-found

I often use Stack Exchange sites on my smartphone. The mobile version works great, but when I end up on a page which is not found (like a deleted question), it redirects me to the full version of site.

Can you please re-design that page to adjust on a small screen?

Comment: Related: [Viewing a deleted question on mobile gives desktop 404](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193152/223030) ([[meta-tag:bug]] with the same subject).

Answer (score 3):

After [mobile web refresher part 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237518/mobile-web-refresher-part-2), the **404 page is now mobile friendly**.

> 404 page did not exist. Now it does.

Screenshot from iPhone:

[image]