# Viewing a deleted question on mobile gives desktop 404

Tags: bug, mobile-web, 404-not-found

Attempting to view a deleted question in the mobile view (as a mere mortal unable to view deleted questions) results in a 404 - *in desktop view*. This is probably not intended behaviour.

> [image]

Comment: You don't like waffles?

Comment: @CodyGray I do like waffles. I just prefer mobile waffles on mobiles, and desktop waffles on desktops.

Comment: Not a bug, there is simply no mobile version of that page.

Comment: It does give you a wierd disjointed feeling whenever it happens